# Перекрывание текста - изменения цвета текста на прогресс баре

Tags: javascript, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

красная линия - прогресс бар, темно-серая - подложка прогресс бара

Как вы видите, первая буква изменили свой цвет(дальше текст также должен менять цвет), после соприкосновения с линией прогресс бара... как это реализовать на CSS?

Comment: Реализацию можно посмотреть тут: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/zkL29/4/ (я не автор).

Answer (score 2):

Приблизительно так

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.preloader {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 25px 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
.preloader-text {
  width: 100%;
}
.preloader-text-anim {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: anim 5s infinite;
  animation: anim 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    color: #000;
  }
  1% {
    width: 1%;
    color: #fff;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  1% {
    width: 1%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #f00;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <span class="preloader-text">Loading</span>
  <span class="preloader-text-anim">Loading</span> 
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xvfz23we/)